# Show and Hide submit button depending on selected value

Tags: oracle-apex

I'd like to get some help on an issue I'm having. I have a button that submits a page , I would like to be able to hide the button by default and show it if the value of a filed changed from "under waiting" to "accepted" or "refused" only.  i tried to do that using dynamic action show and hide but i can not .What is the best way to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is wrong with your code if the only hint you give is "i can not" :).

This works for me:

- Create a page with a region that has item `P85_SELECTLIST`, a hidden item `P85_OLD_STATUS` and a button SUBMIT.
- create a computation on `P85_OLD_STATUS` (process point: after `P85_SELECTLIST` has been initialized) of type item with value `P85_SELECTLIST`. This sets `P85_OLD_STATUS` to the value that `P85_SELECTLIST` has at page load.
- define `P85_SELECTLIST` as "Static Values" with values:

[image]

- Create a dynamic action on page load with action "Hide" button SUBMIT.
- Create a dynamic action on change of `P85_SELECTLIST` (note that the values are the return values, not the display values). Add a server side condition to this dynamic action (this will ensure the dynamic action never fires if the initial value is not UNDERWAITING).

[image]

- Add a true action of "Show" button SUBMIT to the dynamic action.
- Add a false action of "Hide" button SUBMIT to the dynamic action.

That's it. If initial value is "Other", changing the value has no effect. If initial value is "UNDERWAITING" and it is changed to ACCEPTED or REFUSED button is shown.

Comment: Well yes, but that doesn't solve "**if** the value of a filed **changed** from "under waiting" to "accepted" or "refused" only" problem.

Comment: i want the button hide also with accepted and refused values and show only if the value changed from under waiting to accepted or to refused

Comment: Sorry read too fast. I rewrote my answer so it only shows on a specific initial value of P85_SELECTLIST

Comment: @dev does my changed answer help ?